# Can I flag a question for moderator attention if the image is not proper?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, offensive, profile-picture, gravatar

A user has posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117640/transfer-data-from-inputstream-to-outputstream-byte-by-byte-in-java) and it has a obscene user avatar,so can I flag this for moderator attention?
As far as I know  we do not have flag option regarding profile photo

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry I do not know how to remove the image,I am seeing this for 1st time.And the image is not gone yet,When I refresh the question I can still see it

Comment: There is no image on the post. If you see an offensive/inappropriate avatar, you should flag _anything_ by the user for moderator attention.

Comment: @SpringLearner: There is *no image in the post*, perhaps you are talking about the user avatar? That's indeed inapproprite, flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry,I am talking about user avatar

Comment: @SpringLearner: yup, and it has been taken care of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the image is the user's avatar then all you can do is flag the post. A moderator will reset the image and message the user (if necessary).

If the image is in the question then just edit it out. If it's obscene then there's no way it can be relevant to the question.

If you're feeling particularly helpful then check back to see if the OP reinstated the image. If they did *then* you can flag it to get a moderator involved. At which point we can either:

- lock the question
- message/suspend the user
- destroy the user

depending on what other content they have and what their attitude is to the original edit.